# Why is the output at the op-amp coming as 2.239 V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, output

What formula can be used to get this output? I tried using the superposition theorem but the output is not the same.

Considering V1 off and V3 at 3 V: V- = 3 V (2k/5.32k) = 1.128 V.
Considering V3 off and V1 at 3 V: V+ = 1.5V (voltage divider).
Thus the op-amp output is: 1.5V x [1+(2.49k/2k)] - 1.128 V x (2.49k/2k) => 3.3675 - 1.404 = 1.9635 V, but it's showing 2.239 V. Why?

[image]

Comment: In both cases you need to combine R79 and R77 as a parallel combination.  If you do your gain calculations using this value instead of 2k, you'll get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your first number should be -3V * 2.49/3.32 = -2.25V.

R77 has no effect (in theory, for an ideal op-amp) with reference to the first calculation (only) since the voltage at the inverting input is at virtual ground. You must also get the sign correct.

Your second number is also incorrect because you failed to include R79.

Comment: Isn't viryual gtound here at 1.5 V?

Comment: @OskarSkog The approach OP is taking  is that of superposition so in the particular case of V1=0 the voltage at the inverting input is at virtual ground and R77 has no effect.

Comment: Thanks @SpehroPefhany for clearing my doubt.  I just made V3 = 0 and V1 = 3V and now I am getting 1.091 V at the inverting input and at output I got 3.268V. Can you tell me how did the value 1.091V came at inv pin?

Comment: At balance (complete circuit, both sources on) both inputs are at 1.5V. Same if V1 =3V and V3=0. Note that if you simulate the first case V1=0, V3 =3V you’ll get an incorrect answer with the given  power supply, but the calculations should be correct.